# Consolidating .htaccess and fix bug

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I should start off by saying that I am no expert with `.htaccess` and that everything I have done with it comes from tutorials I followed.

I have edited the stock standard `.htaccess` file that ships with Laravel to include lines that

- remove public from the URL
- force https
- redirect requests for www.mysite.com to mysite.com

The issue that I have currently, is that when I visit the route `mysite.com/sitemap` or `www.mysite.com/sitemap` it generates a new sitemap and then redirects to `mysite.com/index.php` effectively getting rid of the pretty-urls that Laravel is meant to fix.

**This is my `.htaccess` file in my public directory:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Redirect www.mysite.com to mysite.com
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

**This is the `.htaccess` file in my root directory**

```
# Remove public
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

**And this is my `routes.php` handling the `sitemap` route**

```
Route::get('sitemap', function(){

    // create new sitemap object
    $sitemap = App::make("sitemap");

    // add items to the sitemap (url, date, priority, freq)
    $sitemap->add(URL::to('/'), '2015-11-14T20:10:00+02:00', '1.0', 'monthly');
    $sitemap->add(URL::to('getcv'), '2015-11-14T12:30:00+02:00', '0.9', 'monthly');

    // generate your sitemap (format, filename)
    $sitemap->store('xml', 'sitemap');
    // this will generate file sitemap.xml to your public folder

    return redirect('/');

});
```

My question is, how can I make it so that `mysite.com/sitemap` or `www.mysite.com` still follows all of the rules in my `.htaccess` whilst redirect to `mysite.com` after following the `sitemap` route rather than going to `mysite.com/index.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorder your rules in `/public/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect www.mysite.com to mysite.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache when you test this change.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I didn't think there was anything wrong with the setup, but didn't have enough experience with `.htaccess` to realise I needed to reorder it.